# Lubuntu on MacBook will only connect to new wifi connection

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, network-manager, broadcom, macbook

I recently installed Lubuntu on an old MacBook from 2007. Through a proprietary driver, I managed to activate the WiFi module.

I am able to see the APs on my laptop and can try to connect to them, though after a while it times out. I found a workaround that works more or less reliably. By creating a new connection with `nmcli device wifi connect ssid password pass`, I can sometimes connect to the network.

The problem is that it creates a new connection which has to be cleaned up and the laptop should be usable by my students reliably without having the WiFi password in plain sight.

The output of `lshw`:

```
Produkt: MacBook4,1 (System SKU#)
    Hersteller: Apple Inc.
    Version: 1.0
```

…

```
*-network                
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
       Hersteller: Broadcom Limited
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Logischer Name: wls4
       Version: 03
       Seriennummer: 00:23:12:08:65:a7
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:16 memory:50500000-50503fff memory:50000000-500fffff
```

The output of `lspci`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)
```

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0088]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

The output of `dmesg | grep wl`:

```
[   19.058352] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   19.058357] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   19.067890] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   19.088080] wl 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   19.212590] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4328 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[   19.215106] wl 0000:02:00.0 wls4: renamed from wlan0
[   29.365787] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls4: link is not ready
[   29.707116] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls4: link is not ready
[   33.244482] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wls4: link becomes ready
[  478.260337] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls4: link is not ready
[  558.047766] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wls4: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` We wonder if the proprietary driver is correct. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated the question to include the output of your suggested command.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: I updated the question again. I rebooted the computer and now can't connect to the network at all, so I don't know if there's information missing.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this can be of some help? I note that your chipset (BCM4321) is not listed. And your connection uses a driver for a different chip ID. «wlan0: Broadcom BCM4328»

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: My chipset is listed in the section "Broadcom STA Wireless driver". in fact it's the only place on that page where it's listed. "BCM4328" might refer to its Device ID.
Also I tried to follow the section on how to switch the drivers and neither of the two alternatives work. Additionally I can't reactivate the device loading the `wl` driver.

Comment: What about this one? It points out some common problems. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers